# how to transfer from contract to another account or contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

I have a function:

```js
function sendEther(address payable _to, uint amount) public  payable returns (bool) {
        bool success = _to.send(amount);
        return success;
    }
```

Now, how transferring funds work, is it first tries to grab the value from the caller's transaction and if it's not enough, then grabs the contract's funds and moves it to `_to` address.

Now, let's say that my contract address has 1 ether. contract has a function which moves 1 ether from it to another address. User calls this function. But user puts 0 ether while calling a function. If that's so, the function would still send 1 ether even though user put 0 ether.

Is this how it's supposed to be ? what if i don't want users to be able to lose my contract's funds ? they can call this function, but it should be their money that gets sent from my contract to another, not the actual contract's funds. I guess i'd need a `require` statement to check `msg.value` field right ?

Do you agree with me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this how it's supposed to be?

No, you can (and should) omit the `uint amount` parameter.

Instead, the user should pass the desired amount within the `msg.value`.

This way, the user (and not your contract) will be the one providing the funds.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, but what i explained there how it works is correct, right ? other than that, about the solution, i agree.

Comment: @NikaKurashvili: BTW, you can (and should) get rid of the boolean return-value, and replace the `send` with `transfer` (which reverts upon failure instead of returning status).

Comment: Yes ! it's just an example code.